# Numbers in li element tag not working in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Number list not running with Vue.js

[image: Output like this]

but this is how I sent it. Is there a solution to this?

The code I wrote for Vue.js output is as follows

```
              p(v-html="selectedProduct.description")
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBWbk.png)

[Html Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NPio.png)

Comment: Possible you want to render it inside div ` div(v-html="selectedProduct.description") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure any of your `ol` or `ul` default style `list-style-type` property is overwritten. If it's overwritten you can override the style under your component.

```
<style scoped>
ol {
   list-style-type: decimal;
}
</style>
```

***Step 1:*** `HTML` template

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="decription"></div>
</div>
```

***Step 2:*** `data` will be

```
  data() {
  return {
    decription: `<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <ol>
    <li>deneme</li>
    <li>denem2</li>
    <li>denem3</li>
  </ol>`,
  };
}
```

Check the `output`:

[image]
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sinoussi-8newi)

Comment: I tried the way you said but it didn't work :(

                  div(v-html="selectedProduct.description") 
Output
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/545x170q90/922/PI6Kbz.png

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/582x157q90/923/PbPJI8.png

Comment: @MehmetKüçükçelebi Have you tried with overriding css style in your component? `<style scoped>
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal !important;
}
</style>`

Comment: @MehmetKüçükçelebi You can try with inline styles, if it not work with previous method `<ol style='list-style-type:decimal'>`